# React different ways of calling a child method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React says we should not use `refs` where possible and I noticed that you can't use shallow rendering testing with refs so I have tried to remove refs where possible. I have a child component like this:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    play = () => {
        //play the media
    },
    pause = () => {
        //pause the media
    },
    setMedia = (newMedia) => {
        //set the new media
    }
}
```

I then have a parent component that needs to call these methods. For the `setMedia` I can just use props with the `componentWillReceiveProps` and call `setMedia` when the new props come in to the child.

With the `play` and `pause` functions I cannot do this.

Ben Alpert replied to this [post](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/is-it-bad-practice-to-call-child-component-methods-from-parent/1821) and said:

> In general, data should be passed down the tree via props. There are a few exceptions to this (such as calling **.focus()** or triggering a one-time animation that doesn't really "change" the state) but any time you're exposing a method called "set", props are usually a better choice. Try to make it so that the inner input component worries about its size and appearance so that none of its ancestors do.

Which is the best way to call a child function?

1. `play()` and `pause()` methods can be called from refs as they do not change the state just like `focus()` and use props for the other functions that have arguments.
2. Call the child functions by passing the method name in although this just seems hacky and a lot more complex:

   ```
   class Child extends React.Component {
       play = () => {
           //play the media
       },
       pause = () => {
           //pause the media
       },
       setMedia = (newMedia) => {
           //set the new media
       },
       _callFunctions = (functions) => {
           if (!functions.length) {
               return;
           }

           //call each new function
           functions.forEach((func) => this[func]());

           //Empty the functions as they have been called
           this.props.updateFunctions({functions: []});
       } 
       componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
           this._callFunctions(nextProps.functions);
       }
   }

   class Parent extends React.Component {
       updateFunctions = (newFunctions) => this.setState({functions: newFunctions});
       differentPlayMethod = () => {
           //...Do other stuff
           this.updateFunctions("play");
       }
       render() {
           return (
               <Child updateFunctions={this.updateFunctions}/>
           );
       }
   }
   ```
3. Do this in the child component: `this.props.updateFunctions({play: this.play});`
   The problem with this is that we are exposing(copying) a method to another component that shouldn't really know about it...

Which is the best way to do this?

I am using method number 2 at the moment and I don't really like it.

To override child functions I have also done something similar to above. Should I just use refs instead?

Comment: I feel like this question gets asked a lot and I always wonder... why can't you define these functions on the parent and pass them down if you have to? That seems like a superior approach.

Comment: @azium Building an npm package on the child and want to allow users to be able to extend the component which means these methods need to be in the root.

Comment: @azium That might work I think but that breaks encapsulation doesn't it? The parent now has a copy of the same child method.

Comment: Sorry I erased what I had because I thought you implemented exactly what was my suggestion. Yes it breaks encapsulation but It does so in the same way as accessing refs. I've dealt with this exact scenario and I think I ended up passing down flags and callbacks something like `<Child shouldPlay={shouldPlay} onPlay={onPlay} />`

Comment: What about shipping your package with a higher order component which you can wrap the parent, passing the relevant state and props down? Something like `withMedia(Parent)` ?

Comment: @azium That's exactly what I was looking for. Post an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: The approaches for some answers came directly from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than call child functions, try to pass data and functions down from the parent. Alongside your component, you can export a wrapper or higher order function that provides the necessary state / functions.

```
let withMedia = Wrapped => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    state = { playing: false }
    play() { ... }
    render() {
      return (
        <Wrapped 
          {...this.state} 
          {...this.props} 
          play={this.play}
        />
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your parent component:

```
import { Media, withMedia } from 'your-library'

let Parent = props =>
  <div>
    <button onClick={props.play}>Play</button>
    <Media playing={props.playing} />
  </div>

export default withMedia(Parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the state as localized as you can, but don't spread it over multiple components. If you need the information whether it is currently playing in both the parent and the child, keep the state in the parent.

This leaves you with a much cleaner state tree and props:

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.togglePlay}>Child: Play/Pause</button>
        <p>Playing: {this.props.playing ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.togglePlay = this.togglePlay.bind(this);
    
    this.state = {
      playing: false
    };
  }
  
  togglePlay() {
    this.setState({
      playing: !this.state.playing
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.togglePlay}>Parent: Play/Pause</button>
        <Child togglePlay={this.togglePlay} playing={this.state.playing} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'></div>
```

Comment: I don't want to set the state in the parent like this because I am going to publish the child as an npm package and want users to just be able to drop it in without setting a 100 different properties on the parent.