# Avoid `OverlayTrigger` from unmounting overlay

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, popover, react-bootstrap

How do I stop the `OverlayTrigger` component from `react-bootstrap` from unmounting its `overlay` component when the `onHide` prop is called? This is the component that shows the `Popover`. It is not an issue with `Popover` since setting `overlay={<ComplexComponent />}` causes the same issue where `ComplexComponent` is mounted every time the `OverlayTrigger` is triggered.

This is a simplified version of what I'm attempting:

```
const overlay = (<Popover id="some-random-id">
    <ComplexComponent />
</Popover>;

<OverlayTrigger
  trigger={['hover', 'focus']}
  placement="top"
  overlay={overlay}
>
    <span>trigger label</span>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

The reason I need to just hide the overlay instead of unmounting it is that `ComplexComponent` makes service calls on `componentWillMount` and takes a considerable amount of time to do that initial fetch. I've considered using `refs` but haven't come up with a good enough strategy.

Comment: can you move the service calls up the tree or in a flux action or something then just pass the data down to the overlay component? seems better than relying on mounting behaviour of a child component for data fetching

Comment: No because it's a blackboxed component. I'm all for re-rendering when react thinks it's most efficient. This case is different because it's the library destroying the tooltip entirely instead of just hiding it in the DOM.

Comment: Is it blackboxed in a sense that you are completely unable to touch it? I feel like this is a really common issue that separating look and behaviour solves so nicely and idiomatically react. something like my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597507/react-different-ways-of-calling-a-child-method/40623959#40623959

Comment: I totally remember that question and reading your answer before replying and thinking you covered it nicely. Yeah so my component is entirely blackboxed. We create components (science based) that know how to fetch their own data, that way the developer doesn't need to go try and find where that particular component's data source is, like a service url that who knows when it was created. In this case, right, it's separating logic and behavior that causes the issue! If the correct behavior is to re-mount each time, then I will work on an API for these components that allows passing cached data

Comment: Then the parent using these blackboxed components can store data from tooltips and pass it right back in if the user were to hover over the same tooltip again. Was hoping to avoid doing that for a while since it's a big overhaul. Oh well ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well before you go down that road, have you considered making your own overlay component which doesn't mount / unmount, but rather toggles visibility? surely that's easier

Comment: Yup, also a good route. I have to add caching anyhow. Still curious to know if the component allows for this behavior. Maybe a github issue would be more prudent.